# Content Security Policy warning on my website

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe, content-security-policy

I have kept google map location on my website and it seem to have caused this content security warning. Is it something that need to be fixed or it does  not matter and if it does how can i fix this issue? The code that has been causing this issue is

```
 <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d4995.103436306331!2d85.31212411204498!3d27.715078206412613!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x39eb18fd1eb139eb%3A0xfbb63e0f0b25c68a!2sReal%20Adventure%20Nepal%20Tours%20%26%20Travel!5e0!3m2!1sen!2snp!4v1594799632468!5m2!1sen!2snp" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0" class="google-map-embeded"></iframe>
```

[image: Warning received]

Comment: These are just warning.Try refreshing the browser and console log should be opened...

Comment: @JeetViramgama every single time i either refresh or go to that page that warning will come but if i remove the iframe this warning does not come. I want to know that whether it may lead to potential hacks or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running your iframe and i got this
[image: Look at my console]
you sure you just add `iframe` to your html file and these are just bunch of cookie problem ... it doesn't really matter. Hope i could help.

Comment: thanks i thought it could lead to website being potentially hacked or something.

Comment: @WigglyFaun i'm glad i could help.